# regular expression for extracting a date from a web page in scala

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying to extract the date September 11, 2013 from the page source of the following page in Scala :

http://www.thehindubusinessline.com/markets/todays-pick/exide-industries-rs-1312-buy/article5117122.ece

the regular expression I'm using is:

```
val dateregex = "</span>//s+[a-zA-Z0-9,:;& \t]+//s+</div>".r
```

and then using it as:

```
val dates = dateregex findAllIn content2
```

where content2 is the page source content

I'm getting no output.
Can anyone pl suggest how to modify my regular expression ?

Comment: you probably meant `\s+` instead of `//s+`, though this pattern seems to match too much...

Comment: I used this finally to extract the date successfully :val dateregex = "</span> [a-zA-Z0-9, ]+:&nbsp;&nbsp;\\s+</div>".r

Answer (score 0):

You swapped the scape character. You expression works fine, just use `\\s+`:

```
scala> val dateregex = "</span>\\s+[a-zA-Z0-9,:;& \t]+\\s+</div>".r
dateregex: scala.util.matching.Regex = </span>\s+[a-zA-Z0-9,:;&     ]+\s+</div>

scala> val d = dateregex findAllIn source
d: scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator = non-empty iterator

scala> d.toSet
res9: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = 
Set(</span>
September 11, 2013:&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>)
```

However, it is a bit too "greed" if you want to get just the date.

Also, if you are applying this to the whole page, consider matching the div class="article-dateline", or better query it and then apply your regex.

I would use this regex instead:
**EDIT:** Changed the example to use triple quotes as suggested by @pagoda_5b, to avoid double \

```
val dateregex = new scala.util.matching.Regex("""</span>\s+([a-zA-Z]+)\s+([0-9]+),\s+([0-9]+)""","month","day","year")
val d = dateregex findFirstIn source match { 
    case Some(dateregex(month,day,year)) => println(s" Month= $month, Day=$day, Year=$year")
    case None => println("No Match") 
}

result> Month= September, Day=11, Year=2013
```

Comment: I usually use triple quoted strings for regexp, too. It makes it easier to deal with escape chars. Like `"""</span>\s+([a-zA-Z]+)\s+([0-9]+),\s+([0-9]+)"""`